# Is it possible to make a role that changes colors (rainbow role)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanna make a bot that changes the color of a specific role (eg. 5 colors/second). Now i can't get it to change the color of the role I was testing it and it worked and i messed up somewhere and i can nolonger get it to work.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def rb_role(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, time=10):
    guild = ctx.guild
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="RB role")
    if not role:
        role = await guild.create_role(name="RB role")
        
    await member.add_roles(role)
    
    for k in range(1, time+1):
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="RB role")
        await role.edit(colour=0xFF0000)
        await role.edit(colour=0x00FF00)
        await role.edit(colour=0x0000FF)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a task that runs every 5 seconds and switches the color to the next one every cycle.

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
async def rainbowRole():
  colors = [
    color 1
    color 2
    etc
  ]

  guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, id=SERVERID)
  role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=ROLEID)
  
  currentColor = colors.index(role.color)
  newColor = colors[currentColor + 1]

  await role.edit(color=newColor)

rainbowRole.start()
```